# how will the timer save the application start time and the application end time to text file?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, timer

I have to make winform application which writes the start time and the stop time in the text file so that the data in the text file can be used to show in graph. Right now I have managed to make the timer to write the start and stop time in the text file but the timer writes the full duration

i.e; 
`8/13/2014 8:33:57 PM
8/13/2014 8:33:57 PM
8/13/2014 8:33:58 PM
8/13/2014 8:33:58 PM
8/13/2014 8:33:59 PM
8/13/2014 8:33:59 PM
8/13/2014 8:34:00 PM`

but i want the timer to write only the start time and the end time.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Start();

    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Hello.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        //FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\log{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite),sb.ToString());
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Hour);

        lbTimer.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.Hour+"Hours");
        lbTimer1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.Minute+"M");
        lbTimer2.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.Second+"s");
        fs.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why use a timer? If you only need the start and end times, why do you need the ticks in between? At startup, capture the time. At close, capture the time. Write them both to a file.

Comment: Can u please tell me the codes? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("Report.txt", false)) 
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("Start Time : {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now));
        }
    }

    private void Form_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("Report.txt", true)) 
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("End Time : {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("D:\\Hello.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("D:\\Hello.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` overwrites the target file, if it already exists.

Comment: Its not writing the closing time...!

Answer (score 0):

This could be one option,gather all dates and write once to the file:

```
        string path = @"yourpathhere";
        List<string> dates = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dates.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            dates.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            File.WriteAllText(path, dates.Aggregate((d1, d2) => d1 + "\r\n" + d2));
        }
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` overwrites the target file, if it already exists.

Comment: yes,that why i provided a path variable to a file OP knows it will not exist to write the data into to.And thats why i write to it one time.If OP wants to do this more then once then AppendAllText should be used but OP didnt especify that in the question.

Comment: This happens when questions are not that precise. I understood that the OP wanted all data in one file for further processing. Never mind. :)

Comment: @Thorias and maybe you are right but the problem is not with your perseption is with the OP not especify that part :)

Comment: Think about what that `Aggregate` method does, and what makes sense in the context of this example code. All that function does is concatenate the two dates with a new-line in between before writing them to the file. There are many ways to accomplish this if you don't have `Aggregate`. I'll leave the solution to you. Also, the argument to `Aggregate` in this example is called a lambda expression. The OP may not be familiar with this based on the question and comments here.